# Solving $\int_1^3\frac{1+\frac{1+...}{x+...}}{x+\frac{1+...}{x+...}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, contest-math

In the Regular season of the MIT Integration bee, the following integral was given $$I=\int_1^3\frac{1+\frac{1+...}{x+...}}{x+\frac{1+...}{x+...}}dx$$If the integrand is called $f(x)$ then I am guessing that $f(x)=\frac{1+f(x)}{x+f(x)}$ implying $f(x)=\frac{1-x+\sqrt{(x-1)^2+4}}2$. So we now have $$I=\int_2^4\sqrt{x^2+4}dx-1=\sqrt2-1+\log(\sqrt2+1)$$Is there a way to arrive at this, particularly without even finding $f(x)$?

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson Thanks for your check, I fixed the OP accordingly. But I don't understand the second part of your comment, what missing terms are you referring to?

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson My guess is that $\cdots =\dfrac{1+\cdots}{x+\cdots}  = \dfrac{1+\frac{1+\cdots}{x+\cdots}}{x+\frac{1+\cdots}{x+\cdots}} =f(x)$

Comment: @WillOctagonGibson They didn't make this clear, but Henry's assumption is what I thought as well.

Comment: Are you asking how to perform the integration?

Comment: @Henry Yes, maybe using the properties of $f(x)$ instead of $f(x)$ itself or something like that. The integral of the radical is kind of hard because after a trig sub there is a $\sec^3$ term and things get a little complicated after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the sequence of functions $f_n$ by $$\begin{cases} f_0(x) = \dfrac1x \\ f_{n+1}(x) = \dfrac{1+f_n(x)}{x+f_n(x)} & \text{for }n\ge0\end{cases}$$

and denote $F(x):=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$. From the recurrence relation, we find

$$\begin{align*}
F(x) &= \frac{1 + F(x)}{x + F(x)} \\
\implies x + F(x) &= 1 + \frac1{F(x)} \tag{$*$}
\end{align*} \\
\implies F(x)^2 + (x-1) F(x) = 1$$

Implicitly differentiate both sides w.r.t. $x$ to obtain

$$2F(x)F'(x) + (x-1)F'(x) + F(x) = 0 \\
\implies F'(x) = -\frac{F(x)}{2F(x)+x-1} \stackrel{(*)}= -\frac{F(x)^2}{1+F(x)^2}$$

Now perform the substitution

$$u = \frac1{F(x)} \implies du = -\frac{F'(x)}{F(x)^2}\,dx = \frac{dx}{1+F(x)^2}$$

to reduce the integral to

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_1^3 F(x) \, dx \\
&\stackrel{(*)}= \int_1^3 \frac{1 + F(x)}{1 + \frac1{F(x)}} \, dx \\
&= \int_{\tfrac1{F(1)}}^{\tfrac1{F(3)}} \frac{1 + \frac1u}{1+u} \, \left(1+\frac1{u^2}\right) \, du \\
&= \int_1^{1+\sqrt2} \left(\frac1u + \frac1{u^3}\right) \, du
\end{align*}$$

While we avoid explicitly solving for $F(x)$, we can use the same method to determine the limits in the $u$-integral.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if integrating without even finding $\mathcal {f} \left( x \right)$ is possible. Integrating $\mathcal {f} \left( x \right)$ is actually standard (*): Just integrate by parts and see
$$
\int \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} \text {d} x = x \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} - \int x \cdot \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} x} \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} \cdot \text {d} x,
$$
where
$$
\frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} x} \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} = \frac {1}{2 \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1}} \cdot 2 x = \frac {x}{\sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1}},
$$
and
$$
\int \frac {{x}^{2}}{\sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1}} \text {d} x = \int \frac {\left( {x}^{2} + 1 \right) - 1}{\sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1}} \text {d} x = \int \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} \text {d} x - \int \frac {1}{\sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1}} \text {d} x.
$$
So
$$
\int \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} \text {d} x = x \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} - \int \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} \text {d} x + \int \frac {1}{\sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1}} \text {d} x;
$$
that is,
$$
\int \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} \text {d} x = \frac {1}{2} x \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} + \frac {1}{2} \int \frac {1}{\sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1}} \text {d} x.
$$
For the remaining integral, we perform the hyperbolic substitution: $x = \sinh \left( u \right)$, so $\sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} = \cosh \left( u \right)$ and $\text {d} x = \cosh \left( u \right) \text {d} u$. As a consequence,
$$
\begin{align}
\int \frac {1}{\sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1}} \, \text {d} x
& = \int \text {d} u
\\ & = u + C = \operatorname {arsinh} \left( x \right) + C.
\end{align}
$$
Finally,
$$
\boxed {\int \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} \text {d} x = \frac {1}{2} x \sqrt {{x}^{2} + 1} + \frac {1}{2} \operatorname {arsinh} \left( x \right) + C.}
$$

---

(*) That being said, I seriously doubt if I can evaluate the integral [within 2 minutes](https://math.mit.edu/%7Eyyao1/pdf/2024_regular_season.pdf). Perhaps there is some very clever way, very nice observation. Let's wait for others.

Comment: It was actually $\sqrt{x^2+4}$ but should be the same thing.

Comment: @Kamal Saleh, yes, I knew. It's just a matter of rescaling: $ \int \sqrt {{x}^{2} + {a}^{2}} \text {d} x = {a}^{2} \int \sqrt {{u}^{2} + 1} \text {d} u $ where $x = a u$ and $a > 0$.