Is this integration solution correct?
$$\int_{1}^{3} \cfrac{x + \cfrac{x + \cfrac{x + \cdots}{1 + \cdots}}{1 + \cdots}}{1 + \cfrac{x + \cfrac{x + \cdots}{1 + \cdots}}{1 + \cdots}} \, dx$$
$A = \frac{x + A}{1 + A}$
$A^2 = x$
$\int_{1}^{3} \frac{x + \sqrt{x}}{1 + \sqrt{x}} \, dx$
$- \frac{2}{3} + 2\sqrt{3}$
Uncertain about validity of substituting $A^2=x$

You assume the continued fraction converges, so write it as $A$, since $A(1+A)=x+A$, you get $A^2=x$. Now in your integral, the bound is for positive $x$, so you can take $x=\sqrt{A}$, this gives the step.

The integrand is meaningless unless you give it meaning by defining your terms.

@Angae Thanks, was concerned about validity of the substitution. @ Thomas Wanted to be concise and thought it was obvious.

Not at all obvious. Is it the same expression for each $\cdots?$

Probably you intend to define a sequence of functions $A_n$ for $n \geq 0$ recursively, where
$$
A_{n+1} = \frac{x + A_n}{1 + A_n},
$$
but it's not clear what the initial seed $A_0$ is. Perhaps it converges for certain values and not for others. There also might be different functions that it converges to depending on $A_0$.

@Thomas Yes. Perhaps I haven't seen enough integrals for it to be non obvious. This was as it appeared on MIT integration bee quiz.

As written, the integrand is up to our interpretation of that formula, but this is not, for example, a standard continued fraction format, so it is undefined without definition. The MIT bee might intend you to "fill in" what it means as part of the challenge, but, as written, it is not well-defined. This problem has nothing to do with integrals, and everything to do with the fact that you need a well-defined function before you can compute the integral.

In any event, I don't see how you can get anywhere until you know what the function equals. What is the value when $x=2?$

Certainly, if it is the limit of $f_{n+1}=\frac{x+f_n}{1+f_n},$ then the integrand is $\sqrt x$ if it is anything - the limit can only be $\pm\sqrt x,$ and it seems unlikely you'd start with $f_0$ to make it negative.

Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864799/solving-int-13-frac1-frac1-x-x-frac1-x-dx/
