MIT Bee Qualifiying Exam 2024, Question $20$: $\displaystyle \int _1^3 \dfrac{x+\dfrac{x+\dots}{1+\dots}}{1+\dfrac{x+\dots}{1+\dots}}\,dx$
MIT Bee Qualifiying Exam 2024, Question $20$
Here is the question:   $$\displaystyle \int _1^3 \dfrac{x+\dfrac{x+\dots}{1+\dots}}{1+\dfrac{x+\dots}{1+\dots}}\,dx$$
This is the first time I see something like this. Are there two infinite sums in the integral? How should one treat the question?

Do you have the solution? Is it perhaps $2\sqrt{3}-2/3$?

My approach would be to solve a fixed-point equation like $f(x) = \frac{x + f(x)}{1 + f(x)}$ to get this in closed form. Then you'd also want to prove convergence.

@Snoop I am getting the same ans

@MathStackexchangeIsNotSoBad, your solution is quite simple, nice! However, I miss the detail that you are equation the result to be $y$ and that $y$ is also equals to $\frac{x + f(x)}{1 + f(x)}$. It is to me that sounds awkward. Could you explain  why that works?

@FuatRay it works because the system converges.  Take a simpler example such as $X=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}$ how'd you solve this?? You'll realise that it is an infinite expression so the expression after the first "2" is also $X$...and then you'll solve the quadratic...it is working in a similar way. Let's take one more example. Suppose $S=1+1/2+1/4+1/8+\cdots$ now don't use the GP formula here I am gonna tell you another way. Multiply the whole equation by $2$ you'll get $2S=2+1+1/2+1/4+\cdots$ in a similar way you do $2S=2+S$ and get $S=2$

Nice! Let me ask you to one more question. Why do we need convergency in general?

@FuatRay because if the expression isn't convergent then it's divergent and divergent expressions evaluate to infinity or some absurd value. Let me give you an example. Let $S=1+2+4+8+\cdots$ Using the same concept we used in the previous comment, $S=1+2(1+2+4+\cdots)$ or $S=1+2S$ or $S=-1$....do u see the flaw?? We know that the value of the sum is infinite.. but we're getting a negative number. That's because the expression is divergent and things work different at infinities.

@AnneBauval I don’t think OP’s question is a duplicate of this.

@Aig My bad. The OP's question is much simpler than https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4864799

@AnneBauval The question just got closed. I think it should be reopened.

@Aig So do I (I had retracted my vote before it got closed, and I just voted for its reopening).

Let $$ \dfrac{x+\dfrac{x+\dots}{1+\dots}}{1+\dfrac{x+\dots}{1+\dots}}=y$$ $$\implies \frac{x+y}{1+y}=y$$ or it means that $$y=\sqrt{x}$$ we rejected the negative one cause $y$ can never be negative.
Now just solve $$\int _1^3 \sqrt x \:\: dx$$ $$=\boxed{2\sqrt3-\frac{2}{3}}$$

Do we need to prove that this whole fraction converges? If yes, how could we do that?

@Aig the question would be flawed if the fraction diverges, so need to prove it here

Other users have already given the correct answer.
It remains to be formally proved that $$\dfrac{x+\dfrac{x+\dots}{1+\dots}}{1+\dfrac{x+\dots}{1+\dots}}$$
does indeed define a function.
Define on $[1,3]$ the function$f_1(x)=x$, and by recurrence $f_{n+1}(x)=\dfrac{x+f_n(x)}{1+f_n(x)}$ for $n\geq 1$.
Notice  that $ f_{2n}(x)\leq \sqrt{x}$ and $f_{2n+1}(x)\geq \sqrt{x}$ for all $x\in [0,3]$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  This is because $$f_{n+1}^2(x)-x=\dfrac{x^2+2xf_n(x)+f^2_n(x)}{1+2f_n(x)+f^2_n(x)}-x=\dfrac{(x-1)(x-f^2_n(x))}{1+2f_n(x)+f^2_n(x)}$$
so, taking into account that $x\geq 1$, we will have $f^2_{n+1}(x)\geq x\iff f^2_{n}(x)\leq x$.
Now we will prove that $f_{2n}$ is increasing and that $f_{2n+1}$ is decreasing. Note that $$f_{n+2}(x)-f_{n}(x)=\dfrac{x+\dfrac{x+f_n(x)}{1+f_n(x)}}{1+\dfrac{x+f_n(x)}{1+f_n(x)}}-f_n(x)=\\\dfrac{2x+xf_n(x)+f_n(x)}{1+x+2f_n(x)}-f_n(x)=\dfrac{2(x-f_n^2(x))}{1+x+2f_n(x)}$$
Using that $ f_{2n}(x)\leq \sqrt{x}$ and $f_{2n+1}(x)\geq \sqrt{x}$ we get the monotone behaviour of both subsequences.
As $f_{2n}$ and $f_{2n+1}$ are monotone and bound each other, they must converge (to the same function). This implies that the whole sequence $f_n$ converges. As already proved in another answers and comments, the limit must be $\sqrt{x}$. Then, the logic can be carried out, leading to the result of $2\sqrt{3}-\dfrac{2}{3}$.

Why $f_{2n}$ and $f_{2n+1}$ must converge to the same function?

@Aig Use the recurrence relation knowing that they converge. The limit can be $\sqrt{x}$ or $-\sqrt{x}$. The latter is impossible.

But the recurrence relation must be of the form $\frac{x+\frac{x+y}{1+y}}{1+\frac{x+y}{1+y}}=y$, since we only know that subsequences $f_{2n}$, $f_{2n+1}$ converge. (From this equation we get that $y=\sqrt x$.) We can’t use $\frac{x+y}{1+y}=y$, since we don’t know if $f_n$ converges. Or can we?

@Aig We know $f_{2n}$ and $f_{2n+1}$ converge, as they are monotonic and bounded. They must both converge to $\sqrt{x}$ using that argument. That implies that $f_n$ converges to $\sqrt{x}$ too.

”That argument” is the equation $\frac{x+y}{1+y}=y$? What is $y$ in this equation? $y=\lim f_{2n}$? Then why is this equation true? Or $y=\lim f_n$? We still don’t know if it exists.

The argument is that $f_{2n}$ verifies the recurrence relation $f_{2n+2}(x)=\dfrac{2x+xf_{2n}(x)+f_{2n}(x)}{1+x+2f_{2n}(x)}$. Letting $y=\lim f_{2n}$ we get $y=\sqrt{x}$. The same goes for $f_{2n+1}$.

You probably missed $-f_{2n}(x)$ in the left side? But yes, this is equivalent to the equation $\frac{x+\frac{x+y}{1+x}}{1+\frac{x+y}{1+x}}=y$ I wrote earlier. And the solution is immediately $y=\sqrt x$ from your form. Now I see, thanks.

No, nothing is missing. The $-f_{n}(x)$ term is used in the answer along with the recurrence to prove the monotonic behaviour.

Yes, I meant that if you subtract $f_n(x)$ as you do in the post, then it is obvious that $\sqrt x$ is the solution.
